# Is there a word for "(to be) haunted by bad memories"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word for "haunted by bad memories" or "to be haunted by bad memories"?

Comment: No, there isn't a single word that means  that. The phrase "haunted by bad memories" or "I am haunted by bad dreams" is already idiomatic. I'd be amazed if such a word exists. Not my downvote.

Comment: an example sentence should be supplied

Comment: Aaron, your question needs to be posed better and then it can be reopened.  Write a sentence showing how you'd like the word to be used, with some dashes in the place where the word would go.

Comment: Not enough in the question to know what kind of answer would work for you. ***Traumatized*** is probably close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strong word to use might be *agonize*.

Agonize via [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agonize)

> intransitive verb:
>
> 1 :  to suffer agony, torture, or anguish: "agonizes
> over every decision", "agonized for days over whether she'd done the right thing"
>
> 2 :  struggle

A less intense word might be *brooding*.

Brood via [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brood)

> transitive verb: To think anxiously or gloomily about, ponder "I used to brood these
> things on my walk — Christopher Morley"
>
> intransitive verb:
>
> 1 :  to dwell gloomily on a subject "brooded over his mistake"
>
> 2 :  to be in a state of depression "sat brooding in her room"

If going in another direction, you might be interested in using *scarred* to describe a person.

Scarred via [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scarred)

> a lasting aftereffect of trouble, especially a lasting psychological
> injury resulting from suffering or trauma. "My children and I are safe now, but we will always by scarred by those twelve years of abuse and fear of deportation."

Similar words: Traumatized, Lament, Grieving, Mourn, Bemoan

Comment: "Traumatized" is very close to what I was thinking, thanks! "Scarred" is pretty good too.